# Provisioning request delayed or failed to send

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have created a new YAML pipeline in Azure Devops. Its almost an identical copy of another pipeline that is working fine.

The build stage works fine but when it gets to the terraform script tries to execut i get the below errors:

```
##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[error]Provisioning request delayed or failed to send 5 time(s). This is over the limit of 3 time(s).
```

This is the first part of the yaml.

```
parameters:
  environment:

jobs:
  - deployment: '${{ parameters.environment }}Infrastructure'
    displayName: 'Deploy infrastructure ${{ parameters.environment }}'
    environment: '${{ parameters.environment }}'
    dependsOn: []

    variables:
      containername: terraform
      terraformPlan: terraform-plan
      storagename: 'io${{ parameters.environment }}storage'       

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self

          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            displayName: Install Terraform
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 0.14.9

          - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
            displayName: Terraform Init
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We just experienced this ourselves. We resolved by clarifying the specific vmimage of the agent we wanted instead of letting ADO infer it. Like so:

```
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

Comment: This worked, however I don't know why. I have another pipeline which doesnt have this and it works fine.

Comment: Microsoft docs for where to place the above (pool, vmImage) attributes: 
The documentation notes:

"Note

The specification of a pool can be done at multiple levels in a YAML file. If you notice that your pipeline is not running on the expected image, make sure that you verify the pool specification at the pipeline, stage, and job levels."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml